# How and when should I use variable/method declaration?

Tags: scala, syntax

I'm learning scala and I don't know how and when to use variable/method declaration in scala.

Here's the scala syntax about declaration and definition: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html

It show that:

```
Dcl         ::=  ‘val’ ValDcl
              |  ‘var’ VarDcl
              |  ‘def’ FunDcl
              |  ‘type’ {nl} TypeDcl
PatVarDef   ::=  ‘val’ PatDef
              |  ‘var’ VarDef
Def         ::=  PatVarDef
              |  ‘def’ FunDef
              |  ‘type’ {nl} TypeDef
              |  TmplDef
```

For example, this is declaration for variable `x` and method `hello`:

```
var x: Int;

class Tester {
  def hello(var x:Int):Int
}
```

And this is definition for variable `x` and method `hello`:

```
var x: Int = 1
class Tester {
  def hello(var x:Int): Int = x
}
```

If I want to write some application with scala, it seems that all I need is **definition**, I don't know how and when should I use a **declaration**.

Does declaration is just equal to **interface** ?
Please educate me.

Comment: `def hello(var x:Int)` doesn't compile. Anyways, the language spec aren't really good for learning the language; it would be better to follow some tutorials, read some books or watch some tutorial. Also, `var` are discouraged and a `var` without a value is not really a good idea

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, not just for study, I really want to understand **declaration** in scala.

Comment: I have been programming in **Scala** for like 5 years now, and I do not really know what you mean with _"declaration"_.

Comment: A declaration is an abstract member, which only defines signature, while a definition defines both signature and implementation. I think "declaration" is similar to interface in Java, but more powerful (I don't know much about Java).

Comment: Normally you use an abstract member (a.k.a. declaration) just like in other OOP language -- i.e., when you want to define some abstract/general API to be implemented by several subclasses/traits.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: Declarations have existed in Scala since before 1.0, and they mean pretty much the same thing as in more or less all mainstream languages. The OP links to the chapter in the Scala 2.11 Language Specification, but the chapter would basically be the same for all older and also all newer versions of Scala.

Comment: @JörgWMittag didn't know abstract definitions were called declarations, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Abstract definitions are a part of what is called declarations, so you would usually not use declaration to mean abstract definition since it's less precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, declarations are (in my experience) used for two main usages :

- method and variable type definitions in interfaces (whether it be traits or abstract classes)
- type "aliasing" for code clarity. This can take the form of either aliasing a single type (`type UserId = Int` ) or aliasing a cake of type (`type Codec = Serializer with Deserializer`)

As you may have noticed, you can't have variables or methods declarations in non abstract classes, since you can't have undefined behaviours at runtime. Undefined here accurately meaning "not having a definition" per the scala language meaning of definition.

So, I wouldn't say that all you need are definitions to write Scala code, since declarations are pretty useful. However, for each declaration, you'll need at least one definition to make it useful !

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to write some application with scala, it seems that all I need is definition

It is possible to write a definition out of pure declarations. For example consider

```
trait Iterator[+A] {
  def hasNext: Boolean
  def next(): A
  def nextOption(): Option[A] = if (hasNext) Some(next()) else None
}
```

Here `nextOption` is defined in terms of `hasNext` and `next` even though the latter two are not defined at this point in time. Certainly, at the point when we *run* the program all declarations will need to be linked with fleshed out objects, but at compile-time we can proceed with writing a program even when sometimes we do not have all the details.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge, I have no idea scala could write like this.

Comment: @linrongbin you can write code like this in any oop language that I know. I repeat, if you want to learn the language the specs are not good, they are intended for language authors.

Comment: The specs are perfectly fine actually. They're not meant as a learning source, but it's a very good reference source.